# Problemas ao adicionar foreign key no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

estou com problemas ao definir o atributo anoAuto da tabela negócios como uma chave estrangeira pra automovéis.ano. O MySQL sempre diz "ERROR CODE: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint".

```
create table automoveis (
codigo int,
ano int,
fabricante varchar(20),
modelo varchar(20),
pais varchar(20),
precoTabela decimal(8, 2),
primary key (codigo, ano));

create table revendedoras (
cgc int,
nome varchar(30),
proprietário varchar(30),
cidade varchar(30),
estado varchar(30),
primary key(cgc));

create table consumidores (
identidade char(7),
nome varchar(30),
sobrenome varchar(30),
primary key(identidade));

create table negocios (
comprador char(7),
revenda int,
codAuto int,
anoAuto int,
data_compra date,
preco decimal(8,2),
primary key (comprador, revenda, codAuto, anoAuto),
foreign key (comprador) references consumidores(identidade),
foreign key (revenda) references revendedoras(cgc),
foreign key (codAuto) references automoveis(codigo),
foreign key (anoAuto) references automoveis(ano));
```

Comment: Você tá definindo a PK da tabela negócios também como FK, não pode.

Comment: Isso já foi uma tentativa de fazer funcionar, com ou sem o "primary key (comprador, revenda, codAuto, anoAuto)" da o mesmo erro. E o erro é somente no anoAuto, tirando ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No automovel adicionaria a placa como unicidade de dado.

```
create table automoveis (
  placa char(7),
  codigo int,
  ano int,
  fabricante varchar(20),
  modelo varchar(20),
  pais varchar(20),
  precoTabela decimal(8, 2),
  primary key (placa),
  unique index (codigo, ano)
);
```

No negocio um id para ele, e um índice único para evitar duplicidade da combinação.

```
create table negocios (
  id int auto_increment,
  comprador char(7),
  revenda int,
  automovel char(7),
  data_compra date,
  preco decimal(8,2),
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (comprador) references revendedoras(identidade),
  foreign key (revenda) references revendedoras (cgc),
  foreign key (automovel) references automoveis (placa),
  unique index (comprador, revenda, automovel)
);
```

Espero que ajuda em algo...

Comment: Essa é a única resposta correta. Vide [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xiieowExBGa6PKV2UhQ9WK/0)

Answer (score 0):

Ja tentou adicionar uma `constraint`?

Constraints basicamente são regras que você coloca em uma tabela, como `Primary Key`, `Unique`, `Foreign Key`, etc.
A sintaxe para chave estrangeira seria algo como:

```
alter table tabela add constraint nome_da_constraint foreign key(nome_do_campo)
references tabela_estrangeira(nome_do_campo_da_tabela_estrangeira);
```

Maiores informações :

> [Constraints - MySql](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-constraints-restricoes-primary-key-fk-default-etc-06/)

Comment: O erro permanece...

Comment: por que você não declara as duas chaves estrangeiras de uma só vez?

Comment: Como ficaria Walter?
Seria: "foreign key (codAuto, anoAuto) references automoveis(codigo, ano)"?

Comment: eu pensei exatamente nisso

Answer (score 0):

Aqui, na tabela negocios:

```
foreign key (anoAuto) references automoveis(ano))
```

o atributo ano não define univocamente uma linha da tabela automoveis.

Não sei o que você pretende com isso.
Talvez sua chave estrangeira deva ser composta (codAuto, anoAuto).